# Update parent ref array to child when child created

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Two schemas:

Compound and Element:

```
const compoundSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    client: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Client'},
    elements: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Element'}]
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

const elementSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    compound: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Compound'},
    atoms: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Atom'}]
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

When an element is created, what is the best way to update the 'elements' reference array in the compound schema. Below is what I currently have implemented, but I am sure there is a more correct way of handling this type of transaction?

```
exports.addElement = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const newElement = new Element({
            name: req.body.name, 
            description: req.body.description,
            compound: req.body.compoundId
        });
        Compound.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.compoundId)
        .then(compound => {
            newElement.save()
            .then(() => {
                compound.elements.push(newElement).save()
                .then(() => res.json({response: 'Element has been successfully added', err: null}))
                .catch((err) => {
                    Element.deleteOne(newElement);
                    res.json({response: 'Unable to add element to compound', err: err})
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => res.json({response: 'Unable to save new element', err: err}));
        })
        .catch((err) => res.json({response: 'Unable to find compound reference', err: err}));
        
    } catch (e) {
        res.json({response: 'Error processing your request', err: e});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of transaction can be handled by [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)